# passing previous activity multiple data to another

Tags: android

i want to pass multiple data from one activity to another e.g i am working on hand to polish every nail with different color  , now i want to move this all to another for other work how to do it..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Nail_Polish.this, Blower.class);
            finger1.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap image = finger1.getDrawingCache();

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
```

i have tried this but i did not understand much. 
any idea how it will be possible

Comment: how to get this data from Blower class ?? paste the code also

Comment: i want this class data to blower class

Comment: I know that what you are doing. I said that have you used any code in Blower class to retrieve the data which you want to pass

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

Comment: i just use this till now, what should i do ...?

Comment: Bitmap b = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imagebitmap");

Comment: in the Blower class used this in OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )

Comment: now i have to fix previous data on every finger...?

Comment: I did not get mean of the last comment ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Blower extends Activity{


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     //Bitmap b = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: its not getting any value giving NULLPointerException at this line

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap"); what will happen when you wrote this line ?? @user3671508

Comment: no problem with it i have done it. just used it and then show it in image bitmap . its working fine . thanx

Comment: Okay ... I thought that was not working. So I used another one